# Why is the space $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{Z}}/N$ a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

So we have a complex positive semi-definite sequence $h(n)$, and consider the space $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ as the set of complex sequences (with negative and zero indices). We define an inner product on $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ so that for $(a_n),(b_n)\in\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{Z}}$,
\begin{equation}
\langle (a_n),(b_n)\rangle = \sum_{m}\sum_{k}\overline{a_m}b_{k}h(m-k).
\end{equation}
Let $N=\{(x_n)\in\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{Z}}: \langle (x_n),(x_n)\rangle=0\}$. Our goal is to prove that $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{Z}}/N$ is complete hence a Hilbert space but I have no idea on how to tackle this.

Comment: Which properties of a Hilbert space are you able to verify ? Which one are you struggling with ?

Comment: @SolubleFish the completeness. I found the proof of the operation being an inner product is quite direct, but I don't know how to show the quotient is complete

Comment: But $\sum_{m}\sum_{k}\overline{a_m}b_{k}h(m-k)$ doesn't **exist** for general $a,b\in\Bbb C^{\Bbb Z}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich sorry that’s a typo. It’s taking quotient on N, not H

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I fixed the definition of C^Z, too. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: That's two down, but the remaining problem is fatal: that series supposedly defining an inner product simply doesn't converge for general $a,b\in\Bbb C^{\Bbb Z}$.

Comment: Unimportant detail: If you look at the definition you see it should be $a_m\overline{b_k}$,  not $\overline{a_m}b_k$.

Comment: Maybe the goal is to consider $H/N$ where $H$ is the space of sequences $a$ with $(a,a)<\infty$ ?

Comment: @SolubleFish That's certainly a reasonable conjecture. We really shouldn't have to _guess_ what the problem asks! (Also just saying "such that $\langle a,a\rangle<\infty$" is slightly problematic, since $\langle a,a\rangle$ is in general _undefined_. This is no )problem for an $L^2$ norm, since $||f||_2^2$ is the integral of a non-negative quantity, hence exists in $[0,\infty]$. But the terms in the sum above are not positive...)